# Sticky columns horizontal scrolling of window not table

Tags: jquery, html, css, horizontal-scrolling, sticky

I have used the Sticky Table headers from codrops:
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/01/09/sticky-table-headers-columns/

and have made a few changes. Working sample uploaded here:
http://codepen.io/dbn14/pen/yyQjjQ

```js
$(function() {
  $('table').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('thead').length > 0 && $(this).find('th').length > 0) {
      // Clone <thead>
      var $w = $(window),
        $t = $(this),
        $thead = $t.find('thead').clone(),
        $col = $t.find('thead, tbody').clone();

      // Add class, remove margins, reset width and wrap table
      $t
        .addClass('sticky-enabled')
        .css({
          margin: 0,
          width: '100%'
        }).wrap('<div class="sticky-wrap" />');

      if ($t.hasClass('overflow-y')) $t.removeClass('overflow-y').parent().addClass('overflow-y');

      // Create new sticky table head (basic)
      $t.after('<table class="sticky-thead" />');

      // If <tbody> contains <th>, then we create sticky column and intersect (advanced)
      if ($t.find('tbody th').length > 0) {
        $t.after('<table class="sticky-col" /><table class="sticky-intersect" />');
      }

      // Create shorthand for things
      var $stickyHead = $(this).siblings('.sticky-thead'),
        $stickyCol = $(this).siblings('.sticky-col'),
        $stickyInsct = $(this).siblings('.sticky-intersect'),
        $stickyWrap = $(this).parent('.sticky-wrap');

      $stickyHead.append($thead);

      $stickyCol
        .append($col)
        .find('thead th:gt(0)').remove()
        .end()
        .find('tbody td').remove();

      $stickyInsct.html('<thead><tr><th>' + $t.find('thead th:first-child').html() + '</th></tr></thead>');

      // Set widths
      var setWidths = function() {
          $t
            .find('thead th').each(function(i) {
              $stickyHead.find('th').eq(i).width($(this).width());
            })
            .end()
            .find('tr').each(function(i) {
              $stickyCol.find('tr').eq(i).height($(this).height());
            });

          // Set width of sticky table head
          $stickyHead.width($t.width());

          // Set width of sticky table col
          $stickyCol.find('th').add($stickyInsct.find('th')).width($t.find('thead th').width())
        },
        repositionStickyHead = function() {
          // Return value of calculated allowance
          var allowance = calcAllowance();

          // Check if wrapper parent is overflowing along the y-axis
          if ($t.height() > $stickyWrap.height()) {
            // If it is overflowing (advanced layout)
            // Position sticky header based on wrapper scrollTop()
            if ($stickyWrap.scrollTop() > 0) {
              // When top of wrapping parent is out of view
              $stickyHead.add($stickyInsct).css({
                opacity: 1,
                top: $stickyWrap.scrollTop()
              });
            } else {
              // When top of wrapping parent is in view
              $stickyHead.add($stickyInsct).css({
                opacity: 0,
                top: 0
              });
            }
          } else {
            // If it is not overflowing (basic layout)
            // Position sticky header based on viewport scrollTop
            if ($w.scrollTop() > $t.offset().top && $w.scrollTop() < $t.offset().top + $t.outerHeight() - allowance) {
              // When top of viewport is in the table itself
              $stickyHead.add($stickyInsct).css({
                opacity: 1,
                top: $w.scrollTop() - $t.offset().top
              });
            } else {
              // When top of viewport is above or below table
              $stickyHead.add($stickyInsct).css({
                opacity: 0,
                top: 0
              });
            }
          }
        },
        repositionStickyCol = function() {
          if ($stickyWrap.scrollLeft() > 0) {
            // When left of wrapping parent is out of view
            $stickyCol.add($stickyInsct).css({
              opacity: 1,
              left: $stickyWrap.scrollLeft()
            });
          } else {
            // When left of wrapping parent is in view
            $stickyCol
              .css({
                opacity: 0
              })
              .add($stickyInsct).css({
                left: 0
              });
          }
        },
        calcAllowance = function() {
          var a = 0;
          // Calculate allowance
          $t.find('tbody tr:lt(3)').each(function() {
            a += $(this).height();
          });

          // Set fail safe limit (last three row might be too tall)
          // Set arbitrary limit at 0.25 of viewport height, or you can use an arbitrary pixel value
          if (a > $w.height() * 0.25) {
            a = $w.height() * 0.25;
          }

          // Add the height of sticky header
          a += $stickyHead.height();
          return a;
        };

      setWidths();

      $t.parent('.sticky-wrap').scroll($.throttle(250, function() {
        repositionStickyHead();
        repositionStickyCol();
      }));

      $w
        .load(setWidths)
        .resize($.debounce(250, function() {
          setWidths();
          repositionStickyHead();
          repositionStickyCol();
        }))
        .scroll($.throttle(250, repositionStickyHead));
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #FFF;
}
/* Component styles */

.component {
  line-height: 1.5em;
  padding: 0em;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.component .filler {
  font-family: "Blokk", Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #d3d3d3;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}
td,
th {
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
}
th {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #333;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
tbody th {} tbody tr:nth-child(2n-1) {
  transition: all .125s ease-in-out;
}
tbody tr {}
/* For appearance */

.sticky-wrap {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.sticky-wrap .sticky-thead,
.sticky-wrap .sticky-col,
.sticky-wrap .sticky-intersect {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all .125s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 50;
  width: auto;
  /* Prevent table from stretching to full size */
}
.sticky-wrap .sticky-thead {
  box-shadow: 0 0.25em 0.1em -0.1em rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
  /* Force stretch */
}
.sticky-wrap .sticky-intersect {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 150;
}
.sticky-wrap .sticky-intersect th {} .sticky-wrap td,
.sticky-wrap th {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* Not needed for sticky header/column functionality */

td.user-name {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
.sticky-wrap.overflow-y {
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 50vh;
}
.map {
  height: 175px;
  width: 175px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 8px;
}
.content {
  min-width: 175px;
  min-height: 175px;
  background-color: #099;
  margin-right: 8px;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!-- Top Navigation -->
  <div class="component">

    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <img src="../homepage/placeholder.jpg" width="142" height="43">
          </th>
          <th></th>
          <th>&nbsp;</th>
          <th>&nbsp;</th>
          <th>&nbsp;</th>
          <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <img src="../homepage/map.jpg" class="map">
          </th>
          <td>
            <div class="content">Content for class "content" Goes Here</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="content">Content for class "content" Goes Here</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="content">Content for class "content" Goes Here</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="content">Content for class "content" Goes Here</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="content">Content for class "content" Goes Here</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="content">Content for class "content" Goes Here</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="content">Content for class "content" Goes Here</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="content">Content for class "content" Goes Here</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <img src="../homepage/map.jpg" class="map">
          </th>
          <td>
            <div class="content">Content for class "content" Goes Here</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="content">Content for class "content" Goes Here</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="content">Content for class "content" Goes Here</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="content">Content for class "content" Goes Here</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="content">Content for class "content" Goes Here</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="content">Content for class "content" Goes Here</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="content">Content for class "content" Goes Here</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="content">Content for class "content" Goes Here</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <img src="../homepage/map.jpg" class="map">
          </th>
          <td>
            <div class="content">Content for class "content" Goes Here</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="content">Content for class "content" Goes Here</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="content">Content for class "content" Goes Here</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="content">Content for class "content" Goes Here</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="content">Content for class "content" Goes Here</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="content">Content for class "content" Goes Here</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="content">Content for class "content" Goes Here</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="content">Content for class "content" Goes Here</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <img src="../homepage/map.jpg" class="map">
          </th>
          <td>
            <div class="content">Content for class "content" Goes Here</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="content">Content for class "content" Goes Here</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="content">Content for class "content" Goes Here</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="content">Content for class "content" Goes Here</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="content">Content for class "content" Goes Here</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="content">Content for class "content" Goes Here</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="content">Content for class "content" Goes Here</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="content">Content for class "content" Goes Here</div>
          </td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
  <!-- /container -->
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-throttle-debounce/1.1/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.min.js"></script>
```

Everything working fine apart from the horizontal scrolling isn't how I'd like it to be. Instead of having to scroll to the bottom of the table to scroll horizontally, I'd like to be able to scroll horizontally using the actual browser window. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want the horizontal scrollbar to always show?  Have you tried using `overflow-x: scroll`?

Comment: Only when there is horizontal overflow on the table. Where would I add the overflow-x: scroll? And then would want to remove the table scroll bar...